# How to bind 2nd dropdown based on 1st dropdown selection by picking item from associative array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having associate array like below :

```
$scope.item=
    {
        "Item1": [
          {
            "title": "Item1",
            "choices": [
              "Egg",
              "burger",
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Item2": [
          {
            "title": "Item2",
            "choices": [
              "Pizza",
              "Rice",
            ]
          }
        ]
     }
 });
```

I am having 2 dropdown like below :

**Dropdown 1 :** Displaying Item1 and Item2 i.e title from both the list of items

**Dropdown 2 :** Displaying choices depending upon item selection. For example, if user selected Item1 then in 2nd dropdown I will display Egg,burger.

But I don't want to take 1 extra scope variable for binding this choices in my second dropdown.

I would like to get it from my item variable only based on Item selection but I am not understanding how to do this.

Right now **I have commented out code for second dropdown because I am not getting how to pick choices from item in ng-options.**

Is this not possible to bind second dropdown by picking item from 1 scope variable?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.item = {
        "Item1": [{
            "title": "Item1",
            "choices": ["Egg", "burger", ]
        }],
        "Item2": [{
            "title": "Item2",
            "choices": ["Pizza", "Rice", ]
        }]
    };
    $scope.myItem = {
        title: null,
        choice: null
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <select ng-model="myItem.title" ng-options="value[0].title as key for (key , value) in item">
        <option value="">Select Items</option>
    </select>
    <!--<select ng-model="myItem.choice" ng-options="value[0] as key for (key , value) in item" >
           <option value="">Select choice</option>
     </select>-->{{myItem.title}} </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the first `ng-model` as an input to the second `ng-options` to do this without introducing a new scope variable.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.item = {
        "Item1": [{
            "title": "Item1",
            "choices": ["Egg", "burger", ]
        }],
        "Item2": [{
            "title": "Item2",
            "choices": ["Pizza", "Rice", ]
        }]
    };
    $scope.myItem = {
        title: null,
        choice: null
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <select ng-model="myItem.title" ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in item">
        <option value="">Select Items</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="myItem.choice" ng-options="value as value for value in item[myItem.title][0].choices">
        <option value="">Select choice</option>
    </select> {{myItem.title}}{{myItem.choice}} </ul>
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but can you explain me this line please : key as key for (key , value) in item

Comment: key wil be item1,item2 etc.. So i Just binded them to your ng-model for the first ng-options. And value in this scenario will be array that follow the above keys in your data structure

Comment: So value will become my choice property for this :key as key for (key , value) in item?

Comment: key will be item1, item2 etc and it will bind to myItem.title. Now item[myItem.title][0].choices will contain your choices array based on the key. eg: item["item1"][0] will point to [{
            "title": "Item1",
            "choices": ["Egg", "burger", ]
        }]

Comment: All right.thank you so much for the explanation.This is the only way to work with the associative array for ngoptions?

Comment: You could use ng-change on first select and store the corresponding array of choices in a new variable based on your key selection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153092/discussion-between-learning-and-vivz).

Answer (score 1):

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
        $scope.item = {
            "Item1": [{
                "title": "Item1",
                "choices": ["Egg", "burger", ]
            }],
            "Item2": [{
                "title": "Item2",
                "choices": ["Pizza", "Rice", ]
            }]
        };
 $scope.myFunc = function() {
$scope.myItem.choices=$scope.item[$scope.myItem.title][0].choices;
    };
        $scope.myItem = {
            title: null,
            choices: null
        };
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <select ng-model="myItem.title" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-options="value[0].title as key for (key , value) in item">
            <option value="">Select Items</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="myItem.choice" ng-options="x for x in myItem.choices" >
               <option value="">Select choice</option>
         </select>{{myItem.choices}} </ul>
```